# How can I remove the black line in GIMP

Tags: gimp, crop, image-editing

Can you help me to delete the black border in GIMP
[image]

Comment: Welcome Hiền Anh Lê! Thanks for posting your question. Unfortunately, GD.SE is not designed to handle issues regarding basic software education. If you are seeking to learn how to accomplish something within an application, please review the application help files or try an internet search with your question or an internet search for a tutorial. We are confident you will find answers. If you have questions about GD.SE, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 3):

This is a basic task in most image manipulation applications - for GIMP, you can use the [crop tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tutorial-quickie-crop.html).

Answer (score 0):

Crop tool will crop the image from the all borders,

If there is straight black line in the middle of the map,
how we can remove with the crop tool or any other solution?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/115210)